# Flex exception stack trace in normal player

Tags: apache-flex, exception, flex4

I have a very large application written in Flex with many end users. Most of my end users have the normal flash player (not the debug version).

I use global error handling to catch all errors in my application and I log and send emails to a support account with the error details.

My problem, is that the errors being written to the log (and sent to the support email) provide very little information (e.g. "Error #1502") and with that information I can't really do anything.

While there are many articles relating this issue, I do have several questions:

- What is the real motivation for loosing the stack trace in the
  non-debug flash player?
- Is there a way to bypass this behavior and provide a more meaningful information? (assuming that telling my end-users to use the debug version is not an option)

Comment: A reasonable number of 1502 (stack overflow errors) are caused by TLF and trying to fix text into a small area and it gets confused when added scrollbars. The latest version of Apache Flex 4.12 has several fixes for this that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

the swf-version should be greater than 18. view the flash feature http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html

Comment: How do I use it? Should I only add -swf-version to the compiler? If so, will the swf work for older flash versions (older than 11.5)? Will it throw an exception if getStackTrace is not available?? Can I use a different target version? (say 10.5)?

Comment: yes, add -swf-version to the compiler arguments. see [the difference between swf-version and target-version](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?373586-swf-version-vs-target-player-compiler-options)

Comment: the swf maybe can not work for older flash versions, you can use swfobject to check the user flash player version and notice the low version user to upgrade